# Django ValidationError (Date)

Tags: python, html, django

I have a system with a search box that searches and displays order.

i customize the the search by making the system search by start date to end date or search by using select tag.

Presently i i search by start-end date, it works but if i search and select from the select tag i get an error which is:

```
[u"'' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]
```

Here is my views.py

```
def search_form(request):

    data = OrderItem.objects.order_by().values_list('certification_type', flat=True).distinct()
    print data

    if request.method == 'GET':
        user_search = request.GET.get('searched_item')
        print "What is searched for is : ", user_search

        selected_tag = request.GET.get('certification_type')
        print "The selected certificate type is :", selected_tag

        start_date = request.GET.get('first_date')
        print "The start date is : ", start_date

        end_date = request.GET.get('second_date')
        print "The end date is : ", end_date


        if (user_search != None and selected_tag !=None) | (user_search != None and start_date != None and end_date != None):
            items = OrderItem.objects.filter(Q(certification_type__iexact=selected_tag) | (Q(created_on__range=(start_date , end_date))) , (Q(order_type__iexact= user_search) | Q(item__iexact= user_search)
                 | Q(certification_no__iexact= user_search) | Q(client__user__email__iexact= user_search) | Q(client__phone_number__iexact= user_search) | Q(id__iexact= user_search)))


            print "items  ",  items
            return render(request, 'i/search_results.html', {'items':items, 'user_search_query':user_search, 'selected_tag_query': selected_tag, "data":data})

        else:
            return render(request, 'i/dashboard.html', {'error':True,  "data":data})

    else:
        return render(request, 'i/dashboard.html', {'error':True,  "data":data})

    return render(request, 'i/search_results.html', {'items':items, 'user_search_query':user_search, 'selected_tag_query': selected_tag, "data":data})
```

The error is pointing the this line of code:

```
if (user_search != None and selected_tag !=None) | (user_search != None and start_date != None and end_date != None):
    items = OrderItem.objects.filter(Q(certification_type__iexact=selected_tag) | (Q(created_on__range=(start_date , end_date))) , (Q(order_type__iexact= user_search) | Q(item__iexact= user_search) | Q(certification_no__iexact= user_search) | Q(client__user__email__iexact= user_search) | Q(client__phone_number__iexact= user_search) | Q(id__iexact= user_search)))
```

am confuse, don't know what am doing wrong

Comment: It's a really complex criteria. Try to unpack it to several lines: Q1 = Q(...), Q2=(...) , and then pass Q1,Q2... to the filter, e.g. filter(Q1 | Q2) . The error is somewhere in the date string from the GET

Comment: You should post the search template code.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `or` operator in your `if` condition and not `|` which  is a bitwise operator:

```
if (user_search != None and selected_tag !=None) or (user_search != None and start_date != None and end_date != None):
```

Comment: The issue is the date error that am getting which is :     [u"'' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]

Comment: @AviahLaor It is, but operates with bits, see [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators)

Comment: @uche But if you search by select tag it mustn't raise an date format error. Or in your case it does and this means your `if` condition doesn't work. Have you tried to replace `|` with `or`?

Comment: if i search with start date and end date it worked but if i search with select tag, i get ValidationError  
[u"'' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]

Comment: @uche Are you using javascript to send the dates to view?

Comment: It is because you always use the date range operation, even if the date is `None` or maybe it's coming as a empty string?. Try to use a default date if not given or try to separate your query criteria.